# open_memstream warning "pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I'm writing some C code for an embedded linux system using an `open_memstream` and I don't understand why I am getting a compile warning: **assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast**

To make things simple, rather than pasting all my code I reproduced the problem with the small example from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (void)
{
    FILE *stream;
    char *buf;
    size_t len;
    off_t eob;

    stream = open_memstream (&buf, &len);
    if (stream == NULL)
        /* handle error */ ;
    fprintf (stream, "hello my world");
    fflush (stream);
    printf ("buf=%s, len=%zu\n", buf, len);
    eob = ftello(stream);
    fseeko (stream, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf (stream, "good-bye");
    fseeko (stream, eob, SEEK_SET);
    fclose (stream);
    printf ("buf=%s, len=%zu\n", buf, len);
    free (buf);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works, but the compiler complains about the line `stream = open_memstream (&buf, &len);`

What integer is it talking about? We're passing in a pointer to a size_t as required by the function prototype.

`FILE *open_memstream(char **bufp, size_t *sizep);`

Is there a problem with this code, or do I need to take a look at my compiler? I want to get rid of this warning the right way.

---

UPDATE:

Using gcc 4.3.2, glibc 2.9

---

UPDATE 2:

Tried the following:

```
powerpc-860-linux-gnu-gcc -std=c99 -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -c source.c
```

Result:

```
source.c: In function 'main':
source.c:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'open_memstream'
source.c:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

According to [this](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), it seems that _XOPEN_SOURCE=700 is available **since glibc 2.10**.

Since I'm using glibc 2.9, what other alternatives do I have (other than upgrading glibc)?

---

UPDATE 3:

Adding the following got rid of the warning:

`extern FILE *open_memstream(char **bufp, size_t *sizep);`

Is there anything wrong with this solution?

---

UPDATE 4:

This worked instead of the extern:

`powerpc-860-linux-gnu-gcc -std=c99 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -c ops_cmds.c`

So according to the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream), need to use `_GNU_SOURCE` if glibc pre-2.10 (in my case) and `_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` if 2.10+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

or

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
```

in your source code before including `stdio.h`. Or with `gcc` you can define and pass the macro value to the source file with `-D` option:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -c source.c
```

`open_memstream` is a POSIX function and its declaration is not visible in your program without this define.

Comment: +1, but I would consider using `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` during compilation, as it's easy to forget a define in some files, or forget to keep it *first*. Maybe you could add something about the best practice here.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko OK, I added a mention to `-D` flag.

Comment: +1, didn't know about this, thank you. Tried your example and still have issue, I think it's because I have an older glibc. See updated question.

Comment: @mikhail The manpage for open_memstream says you have to define            _GNU_SOURCE to make the function available in glibc versions prior to glibc 2.10. You might consider using -std=gnu99 as well.

Comment: @nos Perfect! I see that now on the manpage and that worked. So `_GNU_SOURCE` if glibc pre-2.10 and `_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` if 2.10+.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining about the *return value* of `open_memstream`, not about the arguments you pass in.

Your `open_memstream` is not declared, i.e. the compiler does not see the prototype. So the compiler (apparently pre-C99) assumes that it returns an `int`. You are forcing that `int` into `stream` pointer, which is what triggers the warning about "making pointer form integer".

Make sure `open_memstream` is declared before you attempt to use it. The prototype is supposed to reside in `stdio.h`, but it is only available in POSIX.1-2008. You have to enable it explicitly (see other answers).

Comment: The compiler can be a c99 compiler. `gcc` with `-std=c99` will not define the POSIX macros.

Comment: @ouah: C99 compilers do not have "implicit `int`" rule, meaning that a C99 compiler is not allowed to assume that an undeclared function returns an `int`. The diagnostic message the OP is seeing would be misleading and meaningless in the context of C99. This is why I guessed that his compiler is pre-C99.

Comment: c99 requires the diagnostic for the implicit declaration. `gcc -std=c99` without the `-Werror` option issues the diagnostic but do not fails the translation.

Comment: +1, thanks, adding -Wall showed that this was the case, question updated. Still unsure of how to fix.